# Configuring Wildcard Domain for Any User Login in Microsoft

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, developer-tools

Configuring Wildcard Domain for Microsoft Login:

Description: I'm working on a project where I need to set up wildcard subdomains for Microsoft login. Our application uses microsoft, and we want to allow any user to log in via Microsoft. I'm looking for guidance on how to configure this wildcard domain for authentication. Any code examples or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Also if any way to hide app information as it shows multiple reply_urls.

i have tried multiple configurations but didn't work as per my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

`Wildcard Domain for Microsoft Login` -> this is what we know as `multi-tenant app` in Azure AD do which differs from `signal-tenant` that only allows users in specific tenant to sign in the app. So when we use `multi-tenant app`, we could `allow any user to log in via Microsoft`.

`if any way to hide app information as it shows multiple reply_urls` -> I'm not very sure what does it mean... Azure AD requires us to set up the redirect urls in Azure AD portal. When our app redirects to the identity platform to let users sign in with their microsoft account, it uses the redirect url we set to redirect back to our app after the sign-in process.

Microsoft offered [many samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype) here. And if you are writing an app with Asp.net core app, you can create a new web app via template using VS add choose the Authentication type as Microsoft identity platform. Then just fill the fields in appsettings.json with the information you get from Azure AD.

[image]